# Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#id_gender1"}

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I'm trying to select a checkbox / radio button by all the possible ways that I can think of, but none of them have worked.

This is the way I am trying to identity de checkbox

```
WebElement selectGender = driver.findElement(By.id("id_gender1"));
selectGender.click();
```

Here is the HTML code

```
<div class="radio-inline">
    <label for="id_gender1" class="top">
     <div class="radio" id="uniform-id_gender1"><span class="checked"><input type="radio" name="id_gender" id="id_gender1" value="1">
     </span>
     </div>
       Mr.
   </label>
</div>
```

This is the error message I am receiving.

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#id_gender1"}
  (Session info: chrome=75.0.3770.142)
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'JEFFERSONPC', ip: '192.168.100.6', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_211'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 75.0.3770.142, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 75.0.3770.140 (2d9f97485c7b..., userDataDir: C:\Users\JEFFER~1\AppData\L...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:63666}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: XP, platformName: XP, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify}
Session ID: 65163859269265511fa3118a5c9b1f79
*** Element info: {Using=id, value=id_gender1}
```

Comment: were you able to locate the element using the same css in the chrome browser dev tools?

Comment: Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55870609/is-there-a-way-to-learn-xpath-without-using-firebug-or-xpath-as-firefox-is-not-s/55870909#55870909) if you need help with how to work with xpath in the browser devtool.

Answer (score 5):

Induce [**WebDriverWait**](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp) and `elementToBeClickable` to click on the element.

Try the following options.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
WebElement selectGender = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("id_gender1")));
selectGender.click()
```

OR

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
WebElement selectGender = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='radio-inline']/label[@for='id_gender1']")));
selectGender.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code

```
  findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='id_gender']")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

--Disclaimer: cant comment yet due to lack of reputation--

the code where you fetch the id seems fine, and no spelling errors in the code either. But it could be that your answer is found here:

[Unable to locate an Element By ID in Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20083357/unable-to-locate-an-element-by-id-in-selenium)

Also: please post what you have tried so far in a bit more detail. You say in all ways you know, but we dont know what that is :).

For example, reference the stackoverflow answers you have tried that are similar to yours

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I will definitely post "all the ways I tried" next time.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine.
Why your error message have css Selector? when you are not using cssSelector.

if using cssSelector then:
WebElement selectGender = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#id_gender1"));
selectGender.click();

Comment: I probably copied the wrong error message when i posted the question, anyway thanks for the help I got it to work after inserting a wait.

Comment: Please add this as an answer an mark it as the solution for future reference

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you are trying to click element which is inside the frame. First of all you have to switch driver on that frame and perform your test script.

```
driver123.switchTo().frame(<some frame index or id>;//Switching frame
WebElement selectGender = driver.findElement(By.id("id_gender1"));//Storing element
selectGender.click();//Clicking on element
```

**Note: If you do not have frame id or index use xpath for switch to that frame.**