# Selenium cannot find element in source HTML

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Given:

- Python 3.11.2
- Selenium 4.8.2
- Chrome as the browser engine

I am looking to find the following inside HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker apex-item-text apex-item-datepicker hasDatepicker" size="32" value="15-MAR-2023">
```

I tried this:

```
browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'datepicker apex-item-text apex-item-datepicker hasDatepicker')
```

and

```
browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[type="text"][class="datepicker apex-item-text apex-item-datepicker hasDatepicker"]')
```

but in both cases I get:

```
Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector" ...
```

yes for both methods...maybe for the search based on "class_name" this is a bug (?).

Any ideas on howto make this work?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: can you check the following: - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57186504/unable-to-locate-element-methodcss-selector-selectorid-gender1

Answer (score 0):

Try using XPATH as below:

```
browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[contains(@class,'datepicker apex-item-text apex-item-datepicker hasDatepicker')]")
```

In case page takes time to load the element, you can try using `waits`:

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[contains(@class,'datepicker apex-item-text apex-item-datepicker hasDatepicker')]")))
```

Imports statements required for `waits`:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things

1. `By.CLASS_NAME` takes a single class name but you've sent it 4.

   ```
   (By.CLASS_NAME, 'datepicker apex-item-text apex-item-datepicker hasDatepicker')
   ```

   'datepicker', 'apex-item-text', 'apex-item-datepicker', 'hasDatepicker' are each class names.

   You can convert this into a CSS selector,

   ```
   (By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.datepicker.apex-item-text.apex-item-datepicker.hasDatepicker')
   ```

   A `.` in CSS selector syntax indicates a class name so it's looking for all four class names.
2. Please don't turn the class string into a direct string comparison, e.g.

   ```
   [class="datepicker apex-item-text apex-item-datepicker hasDatepicker"]
   ```

   This defeats a lot of the flexibility of CSS selectors to specify multiple classes and have them be in any order, etc. See my CSS selector in point #1.

My guess is that at least one of the classes in that element is not always there. Maybe in some cases it's a different color or disabled, etc. where the classes aren't always the same. Look at the different states of that INPUT and find the classes that are always present and create a CSS selector with just those classes, e.g.`input.datepicker.apex-item-datepicker` as a guess.